# Rhetoric figures in a Pratchett quote

Tags: rhetorical-devices

Or at least I think it was Pratchett taking a potshot at religion (exact wording unknown either):
"When you got them by the balls, you, uhm, got them by the balls."

Note that *both* parts of the sentence are metaphorical, meaning about
"When you control their sexuality, you control them totally".

Which rhetoric figures are involved here (is the one metapher more, uhm,
metaphorous than the other since the first part involves actual balls,
at least pars pro toto or so)? Seems to be quite a lot...

Comment: The phrase is not about sexuality, see [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-by-the-balls) *to have someone in a situation where you have complete power over them*. I'm pretty sure there must be a duplicate question.

Comment: There is no consensual classification of metaphors. [Nordquist's articles here](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-conceptual-metaphor-1689899) and [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/metaphor-figure-of-speech-and-thought-1691385) etc are worth reading, though.

Comment: I don’t think the metaphor is about sexuality. It has more to do with the literal description of the act of getting someone by the balls. The physical harm is so strong that they would do anything  they are told to so that the hard grip is released.

Comment: I can't find a typical [Blackadder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackadder) simile, which goes "as ... as [the same thing]".

Comment: Can you quote the surrounding paragraph to provide context?

Comment: @WeatherVane: are you searching for *as stuck as Sticky the stick insect stuck on a sticky bun*?  (only an approximation, memory fails, etc)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark there is the "cunning fox with a degree" one, and others, but I was trying to find, perhaps more direct like, say, "he is as bad as a bad person".

Comment: You know it's based on a well-known quote, just Pratchetted up in his inimitable way? "If you've got them by the balls, their hearts and minds will follow." [Attributed to many, possibly from the late 60s]

Comment: @Tetsujin: My googled source said John Wayne. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find an actual Pratchett source beyond a pig-latined version of your version "Cuius Testiculos Habes, Habeas Cardia Et Cerebellum".

Comment: Well, Pratchett's biggest pot shots at religion were probably Small Gods [Om] & Monstrous Regiment [Nuggan] but I don't recall that specific phrase, tbh.